# How would you represent EOF in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do something like

```
read -d EOF stdin

for word in $stdin; do stuff; done
```

where I want to replace 'EOF' for an actual representation of the end of file character.

**Edit:** Thanks for the answers, that was indeed what I was trying to do. I actually had a facepalm moment when I saw `stdin=$(cat)` lol

Just for kicks though how would you go about matching something like a C-d (or C-v M-v etc), basically just a character combined with Control, Alt, Shift, whatever in bash?

Answer (score 15):

There isn't an end-of-file character really. When you press Ctrl-d or similar characters, the terminal driver signals to the reading application that the end of file has been reached, by returning an invalid value. The same is done by the operation system, when you have reached the end of the file. This is done by using an integer instead of a byte (so you have range similar to -2^16 .. 2^16, instead of only 0..255) and returning an out-of-range value - usually `-1`. But there is no character that would represent `eof`, because its whole purpose is to be **not** a character. If you want to read everything from stdin, up until the end of file, try

```
stdin=$(cat)
for word in $stdin; do stuff; done
```

That will however read the whole standard input into the variable. You can get away with only allocating memory for one line using an array, and make `read` read words of a line into that array:

```
while read -r -a array; do 
    for word in "${array[@]}"; do 
        stuff;
    done
done
```

Comment: In Unix, EOF *is* a character.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character

Comment: you are wrong, while the article is right. it says "EOT is used to signal an end-of-file" and my answer says "When you press ... the terminal driver signals to the reading application that the end of file has been reached". That signalling could be done by EOT, but it's not "the EOF character"

Comment: rather, it's *one* way to trigger an EOF read. another way is for an operation system when the end of file has been reached... or for your toaster when there has not been any user interaction... you clearly mix up different concepts.

Comment: EOT/EOF is a "control character" in ASCII.  See <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII>.  Where is a reference of this "terminal driver" behavior you describe? It's new to me.

Comment: the terminal driver is a piece of software that implement an interface consisting of read/write and so on.. like any other driver. it's writing/reading from a terminal or an emulator thereof ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal )

Comment: the EOT you refer to is only one way to trigger an EOF to the reading program. it's not "the eof character". as said, eof isn't a character. you can change what character triggers an EOF by saying "stty eof A" (or any other character). then, pressing "A" on the terminal will signal "EOF".

Comment: but that does not at all mean that now "A is eof" . i were never in the situation where i had to write a terminal emulator or driver therefor, but i of course know the basic stuff about it. the driver for example usually implements the echoing (displaying characters that were pressed).

Comment: i see where you're confused. i can agree with you that true EOF is not a character. but it's not the terminal that manages it. what you're describing is still ^D (0x04).  i think i've found the answer.

Comment: Handling of the "true EOF" is done at a lower level by the operating system--on Unix-ish systems, this is the standard library. See <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output>.

Comment: So, there are two EOF values. In the context of Bash (or terminals as you tried to explain), there *is* an EOF character.  Denying its existence confuses the question.  Thanks for the discussion.  I don't program in C, so I often need to remind myself how this works.

Comment: i'm not confused about it. as you see on my answer i know what an eof is and as you see on my other answers i know about C input/output functions :) as you see on this answer, i also know that the operation system can signal an eof when reading a file out of its bound.

Comment: and EOF has no value. it's a condition. like "network communication ended", or "transmission ended", or "end of file reached" or whatever. anyway i still don't see the problem with my answer. i think i will never understand the problem with it :) please read it again, maybe you overlooked something

Comment: if it really contains any serious error or misinformation, we will find out some day. also like Darron comments on the answer of Daniel, he would probably also comment on the answer of yours. C-d is only a very common way to trigger an EOF condition. cheers :)

Comment: I guess my criticism isn't that you're wrong or confused, just that you mention a definition of EOF that doesn't apply in shell programming.

Answer (score 11):

To find what a control character is, run

```
$ cat | od -b
^D
0000000 004 012
0000002
```

I typed <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>^D</kbd> after issuing the command, and then <kbd>RET</kbd> and another <kbd>^D</kbd> (unquoted) and the result is that EOF is octal 004.

Combining that result with `read(1)`:

```
$ read -d "$(echo -e '\004')" stdin
foo
bar quuz^Hx
^D
$ echo "$stdin"
foo
bar quux
$ for word in $stdin; do echo $word; done
foo
bar
quux
```

Yes, I typed <kbd>^H</kbd> above for backspace to see if `read(1)` did the right thing.  It does.

Comment: EOT is 0x04. EOF is nothing. just do ^D only on the terminal, and you see od displays no byte, precisely *because* EOF is no character but just a symbolic number. if it were as you say, how could we ever read a binary file containing 0x04??

Comment: I tried it, and it stops reading the file.  At the user level, EOF is 0x04.  At the programmer's level it's not a character, it's a value.  You wouldn't be using read with a binary file, anyway.  You should be programming in C.

Comment: You can simplify `"$(echo -e '\004')"` to `$'\x04'`. Note, however, that what you're doing here is in effect _emulating_ normal `^-D` handling, because `read` - for reasons unknown to me - _deactivates it_ when the `-d` option is used. Therefore, _unlike in the normal case_, `^-D` is actually sent _as character `0x04`_ to `read`, which then terminates reading because `0x04` _happens to be defined as the custom delimiter_. At the end of the day, simply using `stdin=$(cat)` is the simpler solution.

Comment: When you say `I typed ^H above for backspace to see if read(1) did the right thing.`, what is the right thing? I assume you meant that a `0x08` (backspace) _character_ was _inserted_ (represented as `^-H`) rather than the character to the left getting deleted. While that behavior is consistent with, e.g., `cat`, one thing you _do_ lose with `read -d` is the _ability to use the actual backspace key for actual backspacing_.

Comment: No, a ^H was not inserted.  Instead, quuz became quux.

Answer (score 8):

Two things...

The EOF character is represented by C-d (or C-v C-d if you want to type it), but to do what you're trying, it's better to do this:

```
while read line; do stuff "${line}"; done
```

Comment: EOF is not a control-d.  Control-d is just the most common setting for the keystroke to signal EOF.

Answer (score 3):

litb & Daniel are right, I will just answer your "Just for kick" question:
Bash (as any command line unix program in general) only see characters as bytes. So you cannot match Alt-v, you will match whatever bytes are sent to you from the UI (pseudo-tty) that interpret these keypresses from the users. It can even be unix signals, not even bytes. It will depend on the terminal program used, the user settings and all kind of things so I would advise you not try to match them.

But if you know that your terminal sends C-v as the byte number 22 (0x16), you can use things like:

```
if test "$char" = '^V'; then...
```

by entering a real ^V char under your editor (C-q C-v under emacs, C-v C-v under an xterm , ...), not the two chars ^ and V

Comment: A more robust way of representing and matching control characters is to translate them into ANSI C-quoted strings as follows (if you don't already know their ASCII code points): `print '%q\n' <press C-q> <press C-whatever>`; in the case of `C-v` you'll get `$'\026'` (octal escape; equivalent to `$'\x16'`).

Answer (score 3):

My own terminal driver, when getc returns the EOT, fclose's stdout and reopens. That way, when reader's getc senses an empty write queue and returns the EOF (non char value) to signal it's closed, user sub-routines such as the `cat' can shift the argument and eventually quit. Thus renders the EOF a stream condition or file marker, no value in the range of ``char''.