# Handling input from script piped to netcat

Tags: bash, sockets, fifo, netcat

I have a system that handles incoming emails to send them to a blackbox application at my job. The high level script is maintained by inittab to always run and runs a child script to do the actual work with this command:

```
$SCRIPT | nc -l -p $PORT
```

The script itself reads from a named pipe, does a bit of parsing and processing of the data before calling `echo` to shuffle the data back through netcat to the process connected on $PORT.

What I need is some method to handle incoming data from the far end of my pipe. When I make a request within the application to close the connection it sends back a string (I can define it to whatever I want) and waits for my script to close the pipe. I currently am struggling to understand how I can add in the functionality to read incoming data from the other end; verify it is the command to close the pipe, and then exit the script.

My script (in a nutshell) looks like this:

```
while true ; do
  email_input="`cat "$pipe"`"
  if [[ $email_input =~ .*escape_queue.* ]] ; then
    break;
  fi
  echo "`parse`"
done
```

I'm open to the possibility of having to alter the program flow, I just can't wrap my head around how I would be able to read the data incoming asynchronously since the script blocks on `cat $pipe` until a new email is received to process.

If its not clear, I'm at a novice level with bash scripting and am always open to suggestions for improvement.

**UPDATE**
I've changed my script call to

```
$SCRIPT | nc -l -p $PORT > $nc_data
```

and within the script itself

```
netcat_response="`cat "$nc_data"`";
if [[ "$netcat_response" =~ "exit" ]] ; then
  cat /dev/null > $nc_data
  break;
fi
```

At this point the script terminates once a new message is piped into the fifo. This means that I will always lose 1 message as it gets read by the script and then the script terminates. The script still blocks on the `cat` until something is read. Worst case scenario this will have to do.

Comment: It's not necessary to use the outer quotes in your assignment to `email_input` and `$()` is recommended instead of backticks. Bash can do `cat`'s job: `email_input=$(<"$pipe")`. Also, to truncate a file: `>"$nc_data"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have nc quit after a certain time from the EOF of stdin.

```
$SCRIPT | nc -l -q 5 -p $PORT > $nc_data
```

`-q` being the option to quit after a certain amount of seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that seems it would resolve my issues but unfortunately this is the result: `nc: illegal option -- q`

Comment: If it is FreeBSD, try the -w option

Comment: HP-UX. Corporate server so I have very little control over software packages.

Comment: @TheCapn I guess you are going to have to manually script for the EOF of stdin, this thread may help you further - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463913/how-would-you-represent-eof-in-bash)

Comment: I managed to get it to work with my addition to `$nc_data`. It has one standing issue that I am able to work around as its a fault with the blackbox application I'm working with. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Grambot got `illegal option` because the flags were out of order... @staticsafe, had `-q 5` between the port flag and the port number (`-p -q 5 $PORT`)