# How to inject EOF for stdin on Git bash on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, stdin, git-bash, eof

I have tried the following keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. The programming I am running on bash doesn't stop unless EOF is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following  worked for me:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This didn't work on my Windows 10. And does not seem to resolve on other StackOverflow Q&As.

Answer (score 0):

There is not exactly an [EOF character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/463944/6309), only a control character simulating "exit". And the CMD around a bash does not interpret <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> correctly.

In a git bash, that would be: <kbd>Alt-Space</kbd>, followed by <kbd>C</kbd>.
Done in a bash without any program running, that would exit the console.
Try it to see if your program intercept the control character and does exit its execution. But it might close the bash Windows all together.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this closes the git bash itself.

Comment: @hashmap That is what I feared. The point is: there does not seem to be a way to emulate the exit signal from a Windows CMD/bash session.